# Unique value of table to view laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, loops, foreach

I have table like the below and i used eloquent to get all data based on key at my controller

my table contain duplication at Error column also Factor Column

```
Error    Factor    Attribute    PK_ID
X1        YY        Att1          1
X1        YY        Att2          2 
X1        YY        Att3          3 
X2        ZZ        Att4          4 
X4        ZZ        Att5          5
```

at my controller i used below code tried to get unique value

```
$Error = table::where('id', '=', $id)
->orderBy('ErrorCol')
->orderBy('FactorCol')
->get();

$errorForView = [];
$first = true;
$errorKey = $factorKey = 0;
foreach($Error as $row) {
$currentError = $row->ErrorCol;
$currentFactor = $row->FactorCol;
if($first) {
    $prevError = $currentError;
    $prevFactor = $currentFactor;
    $first = false;
}
if($currentError !== $prevError) {
    $errorKey++;
}
if($currentFactor !== $prevFactor) {
    $factorKey++;
}
$errorForView[$errorKey]['error'] = $currentError;
$errorForView[$errorKey]['factors'][$factorKey]['factor'] = $currentFactor;
$errorForView[$errorKey]['factors'][$factorKey]['attributes'][] = $row- 
>AttributeCol;
$prevError = $currentError;
$prevFactor = $currentFactor;
}
return view('view')->with('errorForView',$errorForView);
```

I need to repeat the below block of code

```
<h6>unique Error</h6>
  <h5>unique Factor</h5>
   <ul>
      <li>each value of attribute based on factor column</li>
      <li>each value of attribute based on factor column</li>
      <li>each value of attribute based on factor column</li>
   </ul>
```

so i tried to use for each with the below logic

```
 @foreach($errorForView as $error)
<h5>{{$error['error']}}</h5>
@foreach($error['factors'] as $factor)
    <h6>{{$factor['factor']}}</h6>
    <ul>
    @foreach($factor['attributes'] as $attr)
        <li>{{$attr}}</li>
    @endforeach
    </ul>
  @endforeach
@endforeach
```

but i found the below result X1 Error name duplicated so how to get Error with each related factors and attributes even if error name is duplicated

```
  <h6>X1</h6>
  <h6>X1</h6>
  <h6>X1</h6>
    <h5>YYY</h5>
    <h5>YYY</h5>
    <h5>YYY</h5>
      <ul>
        <li>Att1</li>
        <li>Att2</li>
        <li>Att3</li>
     </ul>
  <h6>X2</h6>
    <h5>ZZ</h5>
      <ul>
        <li>Att4</li>
     </ul>
  <h6>X4</h6>
    <h5>ZZ</h5>
      <ul>
        <li>Att5</li>
     </ul>
```

Comment: does your table have an id column, if so, is it the primary key?

Comment: Yes it contain ID primary key

Comment: so when you call `table::where('id', '=', $id)->get();` it only returns one row.

Comment: No i get data set with a different id not my primary key the problem is how to represent my data at the view

Comment: so you want group by error then group by factor ?

Comment: Exactly Group by Error then Factor then list of Attributes but Error may be the same name with different factors and attributes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might consider adjusting your database model but here is one way you could do it with your current setup:

```
// order is important for this to work ...
$Error = table::where('id', '=', $id)
    ->orderBy('ErrorCol')
    ->orderBy('FactorCol')
    ->get();

$errorForView = [];
$first = true;
$errorKey = $factorKey = 0;
foreach($Error as $row) {
    $currentError = $row->ErrorCol;
    $currentFactor = $row->FactorCol;
    if($first) {
        $prevError = $currentError;
        $prevFactor = $currentFactor;
        $first = false;
    }
    if($currentError !== $prevError) {
        $errorKey++;
    }
    if($currentFactor !== $prevFactor) {
        $factorKey++;
    }
    $errorForView[$errorKey]['error'] = $currentError;
    $errorForView[$errorKey]['factors'][$factorKey]['factor'] = $currentFactor;
    $errorForView[$errorKey]['factors'][$factorKey]['attributes'][] = $row->AttributeCol;
    $prevError = $currentError;
    $prevFactor = $currentFactor;
}
return view('view')->with('errorForView',$errorForView);
```

That was somewhat ugly but it allows for something more simple in your view:

```
@foreach($errorForView as $error)
    <h6>{{$error['error']}}</h6>
    @foreach($error['factors'] as $factor)
        <h5>{{$factor['factor']}}</h5>
        <ul>
        @foreach($factor['attributes'] as $attr)
            <li>{{$attr}}</li>
        @endforeach
        </ul>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

With the data you provided, this should result in:

```
<h6>X1</h6>
    <h5>YY</h5>
    <ul>
        <li>Att1</li>
        <li>Att2</li>
        <li>Att3</li>
    </ul>
<h6>X2</h6>
    <h5>ZZ</h5>
    <ul>
        <li>Att4</li>
    </ul>
<h6>X4</h6>
    <h5>ZZ</h5>
    <ul>
       <li>Att5</li>
   </ul>
```

Comment: Great it work but only but only if Error not repeat
in my case i have got all Error with the same name at <h5>{{$error['error']}}</h5>

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "only if error not repeat" ... can you update your question with the data that is causing the problem?

Comment: Hi Peter thanks for help question updated the problem is that your logic is great but in case $prevError = $currentError; $errorKey++ is not achieved so all Error with the same name will not split

Comment: If the first row has error = X1 and the second row has error = X1, you only want that to display once in the view, correct? We only increase the $errorKey when the error is different. Sorry, I'm still not understanding what you need here.

Comment: i will explain more each Error have factors and attributes & Error name may be duplicated with different factor and attribute for example error name "critical to customer" can be with different factors and what i need to repeat block of code each time with error name and related factors and attributes  
plz check this screenshot goo.gl / a3HKMM

Comment: I think the code in my answer does what you are describing. I've updated it to show the output I am getting when I run it with the data you provided.

Comment: Thank you so much problem solved thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

It's going to be a bit ugly. You've got to remember the 'current' value of each of the headers then only output when it changes. Something like:

```
@php $h6 = '';@endphp
@php $h5 = '';@endphp
@foreach($Error as $err)
    @if ($h6 != $Error->ErrorCol)
        <h6>{{$Error->ErrorCol}}</h6>
        @php $h6 = $Error->ErrorCol;@endphp
    @endif
    @if ($h5 != $Error->FactorCol)
        <h5>{{$Error->FactorCol}}</h5>
        @php $h5 = $Error->FactorCol;@endphp
    @endif
    <ul>
        <li>{{$Error->AttributeCol}}</li>
    </ul>
@endforeach
```

Won't be exactly like that, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is multi leveled grouped array.

**Controller**

```
$first_level_grouped_erros = table::where('id', $id)->get()->groupBy->ErrorCol;

$final_array = collect();

foreach($first_level_grouped_erros as $errors) {

    $second_level_geouped_errors = $errors->groupBy->FactorCol;

    $final_array->put($errors->first()->ErrorCol, $second_level_geouped_errors);
}

return view('view')->with('errorForView',$final_array);
```

**View**

```
@foreach($final_array as $error_name => $name_group)

    <h6>{{ $error_name }}</h6>

    @foreach($name_group as $factor_name => $factor_group)

        <h5>{{ $factor_name }}

        @foreach($factor_group as $error)

        <li>{{ $error->AttributeCol }}</li>
        <!-- here AttributeCol is an example. there the the Complete Error Object here. print whatever you want. -->

        @endforeach

    @endforeach

@endforeach
```